AdS$_3$ Geodesics' Length in ambient space as done in "Aspects of Holographic Entanglement Entropy"
I have been following the mentioned paper ("Aspects of Holographic Entanglement Entropy" hep-th/0605073 by Shinsei Ryu and Tadashi Takayanagi), trying to get into AdS/CFT. In section 6.2 they go on to calculate the geodesic's length using the ambient space coordinates $\Re^{2,2}$. The geodesics are given by the following expression:
$\vec{X}=\frac{R}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}\sinh(\frac{\lambda}{R})\cdot\vec{x}+R\left[\cosh(\frac{\lambda}{R})-\frac{a}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}\sinh(\frac{\lambda}{R})\right]\cdot\vec{y}\quad$  (6.4)
Where :

$\vec{x}=\left(\cosh(\rho_0) \cos(t), \cosh(\rho_0) \sin(t), \sinh(\rho_0) , 0\right)$
$\vec{y}=(\cosh(\rho_0)  \cos(t), \cosh(\rho_0)  \sin(t), \sinh(\rho_0)  \cos(2πl/L), \sinh(\rho_0)  \sin(2πl/L))$
$a=1 + 2 \sinh^2 \rho_0 \sin^2 (πl/L)$

Since we are in AdS3 the coordinates relevant are $\rho$ which has the cut off point $\rho_0$, t and $\theta\in\left[0,\frac{2\pi l}{L}\right] $. $\lambda$ is an affine parameter and R is the AdS3 radius.
The issue is that for the life of me I can't understand how one derives (6.4). Any help is appreciated.

I'm not presently able to go through the paper and do an explicit check, but if you take the metric and calculate the geodesic distance this should come out by integrating $ds$.  I'll try to check this, and if not may thy Mathematica chip and calculate.
